# domain relational calculus "for all" expression

Tags: relational-database, domain-calculus

I have database of University like below:

```
Student (SID, name, family, mean, age, city, street, CID)
Instructor (IID, name, family, salary, city, street, CID)
College (CID, name, city)
```

How can i answer the following query in Domain Relational Calculus (DRC) ?

"Find instructors who are in **all** colleges located in London"

Answer (score 1):

Find all the instructors such that there does not exist any college located in London such that the instructor is not in that college.

But the question is a bit questionable given that your db structure seems to allow any instructor to "be in" at most one single college, at any time.

Answer (score 0):

When you have to solve this kind of jobs, you have to follow these steps:

1. Search for all instructors that **are not** in at least one college located in London
2. Take the whole list of instructors and **subtract** from this list the list found at **1**

Anyway, since your DB links through an external key (**CID** in Instructor) Instructors to Colleges, you can have **at most** ONE Instructor for College.

To be able to link more instructors to more college you have to insert one additional table to design an N:M relationship, like in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model))